# Is it possible to set pricing for Products based on weight on Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im developing a new site that has been related to jewellery industry which deals with gold and silver. I wanna set the pricing of the product based on its weight(in terms of grams mostly). Since the price of gold is changing daily, it has been to reflect on the product pricing. So I like to add a master control to update the price of  gold and silver in terms of grams on daily basis and it should make the product price changes automatically. Is there any plugins there to customize it or code to enable this function..?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

You can add this to functions.php

```
define ('GOLD_PRICE', '2.00'); // Define the factor you wish to multiply with
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'calculate_price_by_weight', 10, 2 );
function calculate_price_by_weight($price, $product){
    $weight = $product->get_weight();
    if ($weight > 0){
        $price = GOLD_PRICE * $weight / 100; // Do whatever calculation you need here
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Thank you...i will try this code and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

For change the price of products on the gold price base you need to do customise code. But using PW WooCommerce Bulk Edit plugin you are able to increase/decrease all product price with specific amount. Try this plugin if it help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but gold rate varies daily and bulk editing seems difficult to the shop admin.. It would be helpful if i entered the price per gram of gold on master section, then price of gold products has to changed with that calculations..